# Understanding reference counting with Objective C / Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new with programming for the iPhone. I wrote a little App. The Part of the App is running fine in the simulator . I do not understand the following:

The Analyzer is not agree with the code.  "Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)" he said.

Is anybody help me.

Thanks...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
  [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"name"];
  [item setObject:currentAutor forKey:@"descr"];
  [item setObject:currentContact forKey:@"contact"];

  [rssArray addObject:[item copy]];

  NSLog(@"Nachricht: %@", currentTitle);
  [item release];

 }
 [rssArray release];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`[rssArray addObject:[item copy]];`

This line produces memory leak, since rssArray sends retain to [item copy], and [item copy] creates new object, object [item copy] will have retainCount = 2, but will be released only once.
You should use [[item copy] autorelease], or assign [item copy] to temporary variable and release it after it is added to array.

Comment: Nickolay is right. It depends completely on your program but maybe you don't even need a deep copy,([rssArray addObject:[item copy]];)most of the cases a shallow copy is enough, ([rssArray addObject:item];)